# Should closing as "too localized" require knowledge of the question's area?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, vote-to-close, too-localized

I'm thinking of questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428345/need-help-allocating-a-far-pointer-on-borland-c-3-0#comment16723794_12428345). Yes, DOS is not commonly used but FreeDOS is still being developed, DJGPP still publishes new releases and there is still interesting work going on in that space.

If you look at the user pages of the people who close-voted, going by their top tags, it's a C#/.Net person, another C#/.Net person, a PHP guy, a perl/java guy and another PHP/python webdev guy. What gives them the right to close-vote a question in an area they don't know about?

Comment: Questions is opened now :)

Comment: I was not involved in that question, but some of us *do* know stuff that doesn't show up in the tags. For example, I get almost all my rep from answering C++ questions, beause there aren't that many questions about Z80 assembly, CP/M, or MS-DOS 1.1. Even though I might know a lot about DOS, it just doesn't show up. Could be the same for the other guys.

Comment: @BoPersson: I share the same disappointment that SO does not statistically correct or allow to filter for questions with too general knowledge. I think its a plague.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Voting to close or reopen doesn't necessarily require knowledge of the question's area. You should vote responsibly: if you find that you don't know enough about the domain to decide, don't vote either way.

For example, I voted to reopen this question, even though I know nothing about the topic, because I can see that there's nothing “too localized” about the question. Anyone programming on the same platform might encounter this problem. “Too localized” would be for a question that can only ever help the asker — for example, a question that has so little detail that people who find it in a search wouldn't be able to figure out if it applied to their problem, or a question prompted by a typo that could only be of interest to someone making the same typo.

So, I agree with you about this specific question, but I disagree with the general principle of tying close votes with tags.