# Why is this question closed as "too localized"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, too-localized

The question in question is [How to build & deploy a Samsung SmartTV app without the IDE (e.g: on Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766653/how-to-build-deploy-a-samsung-smarttv-app-without-the-ide).  The asker is looking for a way to deploy a Samsung Smart TV application without using the IDE which is only available for Windows machines.

A few days ago, I raised the fact that it was closed in the JavaScript chat room, and most agreed that it should not have been closed.  So, together, we reopened it and I posted my answer based on my own experience with the same problem.  Immediately after reopening, it received 1 close vote again from someone in the channel who must not have agreed with the reopening.  After that, it must have appeared in the review section and received subsequent close votes to close it again.

The definition of "too localized" is as follows:

> This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet.

Well, we can rule out small geographic area, specific moment in time or extraordinarily narrow situation.  *'Unlikely to help any future visitors'*? Well, I was looking for help with this problem before, if it had remained open then it may have had some answers and I might not have had to spend a long time researching it for myself.  Can anyone confirm that it is too localized and give a better reason for it?

I've added my answer, so you might be wondering why I care if it's closed or not.  Well, my answer isn't definitive.  Someone could come up with a solution to get the SDK or emulator running under Wine, or they may discover some software that builds and deploys.  I'd like to add the question to my favourites so that I get an alert if more answers are added.

I just can't see how it is too localized, is it just me?

Comment: By the way this question will be closed as `too-localized`. :)

Comment: I'm guessing that the question was considered by the close-voters to relate to an 'extraordinarily narrow situation'. I do not know anything about the topic in the question, but on first glance I disagree.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From reading through the question the thing that stands out to me is the actual question part:

> Could someone point me to a source for the full deployment requirements & app bundle requirements? Or even just a working sample?

Something which reads "please provide a link or example code" is not really of the type of "practical problems you face"-question which we would like to see.

The actual answer you provided is however far better than the type of information asked for. And in some sense you've rescued the question. So good on you.

Were the OP to have phrased his question along the lines of "How can I achieve X?" then I can only assume the question would have been less likely to be closed.

Why too localized? I am not entirely sure whether or not I would have gone with that reasoning. But one could argue that by the very fact of links being the request, they might ultimately only be of importance to the OP's current situation and not be future-proof. I don't entirely subscribe to that notion, but also feel that with the question in its current form, closure is very likely to happen. NARQ or Not-constructive, might have come a bit closer. But that's really a moot point.

Comment: do you think it was correctly defined as "too localized", yes or no?

Comment: I guess the question read, to me, the way I would have asked it even though it wasn't phrased like that.  However, it looks like the question has been improved a little (although still asks for links) and is reopened, which means it is available to future answerers.

Comment: @AndyE'shead That's the thing. Sometimes all it takes is some simple rephrasing to ask a good question. Ask about the problem you need to solve. Don't asked for links to content that might solve your problem. If you feel (clearly having understood the question) that you might be able to rephrase it to be more in line with a good question, by all means go ahead.

Comment: @YauhenYakimovich I think I've given my view on that in the very last paragraph, have I not?

Comment: @Bart: my understanding of your answer: no it is not "too localized" or it is difficult to decide. In any case, after investing that much time myself into what the closing remark "too localized" means - it is a clear **no** for "too localized" IMO, since the question in its current and previous forms is "likely to help some future visitors". In general, I am again surprised with the high level of rhetoric and evaluation involved into producing a good SO question :) but apparently this is how the mechanism ticks

Comment: @YauhenYakimovich It's to some extent how we maintain the quality of the site.

Answer (score -4):

<strike>It is an example of a question that touches [a topic beyond expertise of an average SO user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147995/should-closing-as-too-localized-require-knowledge-of-the-questions-area?rq=1). IMO people just bashed the question because they have no clue on the subject of smartTV apps, don't work with them daily and don't know good IDEs. Note: there were no comments to paraphrase the question. As the very last resort, instead of down-voting or closing one can just edit the question himself.</strike>

PS

SO is a strict community and I like it a lot. But what SO still can not capture properly is to statistically correct for the hyped topics or popularity questions related which are in most cases trivial or stupid or too common knowledge. On the other hand, knowledge that require specific knowledge (that you can not google for) get neglected.

EDIT

This is not the main factor, but it does seems be a partial explanation.

Revisiting my previous answer after *Bart's* argument, I had a change of opinion and have to correct myself.

I believe that with multiple possible explanations the following are those that most likely were to take place:

1. “too localized” close reason is ambiguous and is known to be incorrectly applied/confuse. So, it does seem to be incorrectly used also in this case.
2. Question has a purely formulated title: "How to build & deploy a Samsung SmartTV app without the IDE", may be paraphrased as "Tutorial on developing and deploying of Samsung SmartTV app (with example)".
3. Question is not specific to IDE or OS and it is not clear what has being asked until 2 last lines at the end of the post.

*(1)* Apparently I myself have difficulties of understanding the formulation for "too localized". (Probably I should read MetaSO more often :-). Luckily, there is a nice [explanation on "too localized"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132319/consider-changing-the-wording-of-the-too-localized-close-reason)

> This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is so
>   specific to you, right here, right now that no one else will ever have
>   the same problem or be able to benefit from its solution.

which should reduce the potential confusion and help to learn how to apply this as a close reason correctly. Now if I read the above quote, it becomes more obvious that "many SO visitors can benefit"

*(2-3)* OP indicates that he has no access to Microsoft Windows but restricts himself from explaining if it is a problem or a limitation. Neither he provides any code example nor any concrete technical problem is formulated. It would be much more helpful if he can upload any concrete progress or reflect the effort that he has done do far by sharing any form of results which he refer to have.

> Also, from what I gather, deployment involves placing the zip file and
>   an XML manifest file on a web-server network accessible to the TV,
>   logging in as 'develop' on the TV and 'syncing' the application to the
>   installed applications on the TV.

PPS

In stead of conclusion, I would probably edit the question to address the points I just raised. That should be at least something productive.

Comment: Just because you can't think of a reason to vote to close the question doesn't mean you can imply that those 10 who did, did so to bash "the question because they have no clue on the subject". I think that's hardly fair criticism, nor an accurate description of the SO community at large.

Comment: Bashing and "being clueless on the subject" are, of course, different but possibly correlated activities. Bashing does happen in SO community. I don't know how often though. It is not my intention to criticize the whole community. I am interested in having tools or instruments improved.

Comment: I have completely rewritten my answer. I boldly admit that I was jumpy in my initial conclusions.. Maybe that would be useful case for somebody.